# Reading Access database files in r

Tags: r, file, database-connection, ms-access-2010

I have read an access database containing 6 tables in R. I am using 'sqlFetch' to read the tables one-by-one. Is there a way to read all the tables within the database at once?

I am using

```
sqlFetch(channel,"table name")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
library(RODBC)
conn <- odbcConnectAccess2007("your_db.mdb")
tabs <- lapply(subset(sqlTables(conn), 
                      TABLE_TYPE == "TABLE", 
                      TABLE_NAME)[, 1], 
               sqlFetch, 
               channel = conn) 
close(conn)
```

... and get a list of all tables in `tabs`.

Comment: This answer seems outdated, {RODBC} doesn't have a `odbcConnectAccess2007` function